# moving elements in and out of screen on 360 degree div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to workout how to move elements off the screen or return back to screen. I have 360 degree equirectangular image. And putting elements on that image's certain points. So when image's view degree changes, trying to move those elements on it too. For example.

```
const mouseDownHandler = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
  clicked= true
}

const mouseUpHandler = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
  clicked= false
}


const mouseMoveHandler = (e: MouseEvent) => {
  if (clicked) {
    elements.forEach(item => {
      item.style.left = (item.computedStyleMap().get('left').value + e.clientX /  window.innerWidth * 100) + "%";
    })
  }
}
```

with the code above, elements are moving but ofcourse on every `click and move` elements popping up where mouse clicked and follows it while moving. I understand the problem. `e.clientX / window.innerWidth * 100)` is always points the cursor. So how can I solve the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to understand what you want to achieve, a codepen would really help if you have one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).